# Highstock.js - Adding a point to the chart dynamically to a new series

Tags: highcharts

I know you can add a point to the chart dynamically via clicking (http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-click-to-add).

But the example above adds the new point to the existing series - how do I dynamically start a new series by clicking points on the chart?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [addSeries()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addSeries%28%29) http://jsfiddle.net/UKfhY/1/

```
chart.addSeries({
        data: [Math.random() * 100]
});
```